# How to get rid of duplicated numbers in YAxis (MPAndroidChart)?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am currently working on a line chart and using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), my problem currently now is that when I zoom I always getting duplicate of the yaxis number.

example:
[image]

I have the source and edited the library which I added the shaded area and vertical limit line text.

what I want is to have a increment values on the y-axis instead of duplicating it. If i there is no fix where do I start to edit the library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix.

The issue is that the library cannot predict what your formatter setting will look like and simply choose "adequate" intervals for the axis values.
Obviously you formatted values in order for them not to have decimals. That is fine but the `YAxis` does not know about that.

So you have 2 options:

- format your values so that they have at least one decimal
- use `yAxis.setLabelCount(count, true)`

With `setLabelCount(int labelCount, boolean force)` you can force the number of labels the axis should use. So if you want no decimals, and can only display values between 24 and 26 degrees, call `yAxis.setLabelCount(3, true)`. Then you should only have the numbers 24, 25 and 26 on your axis, and no duplicate entries.

In addition, you can optimize things by setting a custom y-axis minimum and maximum value.